# Defining interval function in Coq

Tags: coq, proof

I am trying to define a function in Coq called interval that given two natural numbers computes the list of all natural numbers between these two. However my definition is not primitive-recursive. Here is my code:

```
Require Coq.Program.Tactics.
Require Coq.Program.Wf.

Inductive bool : Type :=
  | true : bool
  | false : bool.

Fixpoint leq_nat (m:nat) (n:nat) : bool :=
match m with
  | 0 => true
  | S x => match n with
    | 0 => false
    | S y => leq_nat x y
  end
end. 

Notation "m <= n" := (leq_nat m n).
Notation "x :: l" := (cons x l) (at level 60, right associativity).

Program Fixpoint intervalo (m:nat) (n:nat) {measure ((S n) - m)}: list nat := 
match m <= n with
  | false => nil
  | true => m :: (intervalo (S m) n)
end.
Next Obligation.
```

As you can see I am using well founded recursion on the length of the interval. I define the measure to be this value, i.e S n - m.

I would expect to be asked to proof that `forall m, n, true = m <= n -> S n - S m < S n - m`

However, the proof obligations that I get do not look like this and are rather confusing. I am asked to prove that:

```
 m : nat
  n : nat
  intervalo : forall m0 n0 : nat,
              match m0 with
              | 0 => S n0
              | S l => n0 - l
              end < match m with
                    | 0 => S n
                    | S l => n - l
                    end -> list nat
  Heq_anonymous : true = (m <= n)
  ============================
   n - m < match m with
           | 0 => S n
           | S l => n - l
           end
```

And that:

```
  ============================
   well_founded
     (Wf.MR lt
        (fun recarg : {_ : nat & nat} =>
         match projT1 recarg with
         | 0 => S (projT2 recarg)
         | S l => projT2 recarg - l
         end))
```

Can someone please explain me why Coq asks me to prove this instead of just `forall m, n, true = m <= n -> S n - S m < S n - m`. In addition, how can I finish this proof? Or how can I make it look more like what I am expecting Coq to ask me to proof?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What confuses you here is that the term `S n - m` is partially unfolded and that you have an additional hypothesis. If you type:

```
clear intervalo.
change (match m with
        | 0 => S n
        | S l => n - l
        end) with (S n - m).
change (n - m) with (S n - S m).
```

then you'll see that the first goal you're asked to prove is indeed a direct consequence of `forall m, n, true = m <= n -> S n - S m < S n - m`.

The second one is simply stating that your measure is well-founded (once more with some degree of unfolding of `S n - m` thrown in). I probably have a different version of Coq (version 8.5beta2) because in my case this thing is discharged automatically.

Comment: Thank you. Why do you have to clear intervalo, what does this hypothesis even mean?

Comment: How can I prove the second goal? I am using Coq 8.4

Comment: SOLVED: This proof obligation goes away by adding "Require Coq.Arith.Wf_nat." at the beginning  which has a proof that nat is well founded.